# Can we escape types, codes, etc. in comments section so that spell check does not consider them as typo

Tags: vim, spell-checking, vim-plugin, neovim

Vim supports spell-check only in comments section already, however, if I have a type name or something not a regular word, it will consider it as a typo. For instance, in the following example, `std::endl` will be highlighted as typo.

```
// Don't use std::endl, it will flush unnecessarily
```

I wish we could use ``` `` ``` to escape them like following.

```
// Don't use `std::endl`, it will flush unnecessarily
```

Is there any tips or solution for this besides adding everything into dictionary?

I really don't want to disable spell-check due to this, so any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Consider using the [vi.se] stack for questions on Vim!

Comment: I did not know it exists, thank you @filbranden

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this syntax rule to create a new group matching a `` `...` `` block and disable spelling inside those blocks:

```
syntax region cCommentNoSpell start=+`+ end=+`+
    \ contained containedin=cComment,cCommentL transparent
    \ contains=@NoSpell
```

To load this for `cpp` and `c` files, add this line (by itself) to a file `~/.vim/after/syntax/c.vim`, so it is loaded after the system syntax files for C++ and C. (The `cpp` syntax rule includes all syntax for `c` so you'll get it on `cpp` too.)

The syntax rule uses `` ` `` as both start and ending delimiter.

It uses `contained` and `containedin` to only match inside comments. The `cComment` rule matches traditional multi-line `/* ... */` comments and `cCommentL` matches single-line `// ...` comments. (Both are defined in the syntax file for C and C++ shipped with Vim.)

The `transparent` attribute instructs it not to use this syntax rule as a highlighting group, so it keeps the normal highlighting for comments in the parts matched by this rule.

Finally, `contains=@NoSpell` is what disables spelling on the regions that match this rule. See [`:help spell-syntax`](https://vimhelp.org/spell.txt.html#spell-syntax) for more details on how spelling works together with syntax highlighting.

Comment: If I want to extend this to quoted strings, what is the name of rule matching for it? I searched in the syntax help but could not really find something relevant. If you know, it would be very helpful!

Comment: @ValidusOculus It's `cString` and `cCppString`. I'm finding those in the source searching for `@Spell`, that's how they get spelling enabled, so it's easy to find them that way!

Comment: Really appreciate it! It works perfectly! Thank you for suggestion as well.